# IIS 7.5 Rewrite module loop

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

I'm having trouble with the this url rewrite rule in iis 7.5:

```
<rewrite>  
    <rewriteMaps configSource="rewriteMap.Custom.config" />
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirects" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>                        
                <add input="{Custom:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.*)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.newsite.com" exactDestination="true" />
```

rewriteMap.Custom.config:

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Custom">
        <add key="/home" value="https://www.newsite.com/index" />
        <add key="/contact" value="https://www.newsite.com/contactus" />
        <add key="/main" value="https://www.newsite.com/mainpage" />
    <rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap>
```

All the redirects in the rewrite map work, for example:

www.oldsite.com/home redirects correctly to www.newsite.com/index

The only exception is when I type in www.oldsite.com it does not redirect 
to www.newsite.com, instead, it keeps looping thru requests to www.oldsite.com and Chrome gives a "Too many redirects" error.

I tried modifying the rule but I only broke it to the point of it not working at all.

Comment: Can you please add to your question full `<rewriteMap name="Custom">`, because u using it

Comment: Just add all your rewriteMap.Custom.config into answer

Comment: rewriteMap.Custom.config: is an example rewrite map, I can't post the real one here, but it's basically it looks like the custom one I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rewrite maps config should be like that:

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Custom">
        <add key="/" value="https://www.newsite.com/" />
        <add key="/home" value="https://www.newsite.com/index" />
        <add key="/contact" value="https://www.newsite.com/contactus" />
        <add key="/main" value="https://www.newsite.com/mainpage" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

And your `rules` section in web.config should be like that:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirects" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>                        
            <add input="{Custom:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Problem was in the wrong `pattern`

Comment: Thank you, I just realised that the root needed to be added too. It works fine.